# python merge many csv files by columns

Tags: python, csv

I want to merger many csv files into one csv file by columns and date should be matched in each row. please help me. thanks

sample 1.csv file:

```
CG_Month    CG Number
2014-09 1
2014-08 3
2014-07 24
```

sample 2.csv file

```
Month   Number    
2014-11  51
2014-08  4
2014-07  75
```

output 3.csf file is like:

```
Month   Number  Month_2 Number_2        
2014-11 51      
               2014-09      1
2014-08 4      2014-08      3
2014-07 75     2014-07     24
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easily accomplished with pandas.  Here is a rough outline of what you should do.

- Read in the files with `pd.read_csv`.  If you have lots of files, you can use `map` to read them all in to a generator.  Make the generator into a list so you can pass `*your_list` into the next part.
- use `pd.merge` to merge them all on the common column.  All the files will have to have the same column name in order to do this.

Something like

```
import pandas as pd
import os
files = [j for j in os.listdir() if j.endswith('.csv')]

frames = map(pd.read_csv,files)

df = pd.merge(*frames, on = common_column_name_here)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment yet (not enough reputation), but if you are working with heavy file, you could go for [pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) or [join](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) methods. If your output is meant to be another csv file, you can then go for the [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) method.

It should go like this :

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_csv(url1, sep =  '\t', date_format).set_index('CG_Month')
df2 = pd.read_csv(url2, sep =  '\t', date_format).set_index('Month')
df3 = df1.join(df2).to_csv(url3)
```

You can also rename columns using 
    `df.rename(columns = {'old_name':'new_name'})`